# Procuro uma maneira de transformar JSON em uma tabela automaticamente no chorme

Tags: json, google-chrome, table, webhook, tampermonkey

minha universidade tem um site meio fuleiro, então configurei uns esquemas pra ser notificado no discord (usando um plugin chamado Distill e um webhook) toda vez que rola uma alteração em uma nota. Porem, os endereços que fico atualizando pra verificar por alterações mostram um texto em JSON. E o webhook do discord não aceita por alguma razão.

Então oq eu estou precisando é de algo que transforme isso:

```
{
"Notas" : [
     {
        "id": 95825,
        "tipo": "PROVA",
        "nome": "P1"
                                        ,"valor": "9.3"
                                }
    ,     {
        "id": 95826,
        "tipo": "PROVA",
        "nome": "P2"
                                            }
    ,     {
        "id": 95827,
        "tipo": "TRABALHO",
        "nome": "T"
                                            }
    ,     {
        "id": 95821,
        "tipo": "PROVA SUBSTITUTIVA",
        "nome": "PS"
                                            }
            ],
    "MediaParcial":"1.9",
            "LimiteInferiorExame":"4.0",
"LimiteSuperiorExame":"6.0",
"MediaAprovacao":"6.0",
"Formula":"(P1*2 + P2*2 + T*6)/10",
"Quantidade":4
}
```

Em algo parecido com isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa tabela foi feita usando isso: http://convertjson.com/json-to-html-table.htm ou isso http://json2table.com

Procurei algum script para Tampermonkey... até achei algumas coisas que deixavam o JSON mais bonito, mas nada parecido com uma tabela.

Caso alguem possa me dar alguma idéia eu agradeco muito pois ai vou conseguir receber as notas pelo discord ao invés de só um aviso como tenho feito

Comment: Por que não faz usando JS ou jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é bem isso que queres, mas é só fazer um laço de repetição no Objeto. Usei jquery pra isso. E ainda bootstrap table para estilizar a tabela.

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>ID:</th>
    <th>TIPO:</th>
    <th>NOME:</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var table = [
    {
        "id": 95825,
        "tipo": "PROVA",
        "nome": "P1"
    }
    ,     
    {
        "id": 95826,
        "tipo": "PROVA",
        "nome": "P2"
    }
    ,     
    {
        "id": 95827,
        "tipo": "TRABALHO",
        "nome": "T"
    }
    ,
    {
        "id": 95821,
        "tipo": "PROVA SUBSTITUTIVA",
        "nome": "PS"
    }
];

$.each(table, function(i, obj) {
    var tr = $('<tr></tr>');

    $.each(obj, function(key, result) {
    var td = $('<td></td>');
    td.text(result);
    tr.append(td);
  });
  $('table').append(tr);

});
```

[Link JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/13jwa617/)

Comment: sim, é algo tipo isso. mas o conteudo desse json está em uma url externa e os dados aparecem exatamente assim: